# how do i return attribute after inserting in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want the insert option in laravel to return an attribute called 'orderid' after it inserts the data in to database.I have come across the insertGetId feature which returns the id of the inserted row, but i donot have an in the table ,instead i have a attribute called 'orderid' .

```
    $id = DB::table('orders')->insertGetId( $data );
```

Answer (score 0):

The get insert id will give you only the Id and morever DB::table will never give you the attributes. It will just return a boolean. Use Eloquent to achieve this.

```
$order = \App\Order::create($data);
return $order->orderid;
```

Comment: Do you have the model Order in the App namespace